# How to print in chinese on epson printer using delphi code and what is mode of Epson is it ascii or Unicode?

Tags: delphi, printing, character-encoding, command, epson

I have to print the content in chinese on epson printer .I have used all commands related to character set and code table(ESC R n) and (ESC t n) and tried to print the content but its not printing in chinese. Can anyone help me to print in Chinese.

Comment: How are you accessing the printer?

Comment: Creating an instance of Tdevice and Tport accessing those with Self Defined Class.and than writing the commands to port on which device is connected.

Comment: Is that really the right way to do it? Why don't you use the printing API?

Comment: We have the actual code printing the data to the printer just we want to print the chinese characters.And also we have send many commands to setpage and all other commands it's working fine.Problem is with printing in chinese.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually We Can Print in Chinese if at all we have Epson Multilingual Supported Printer and that too it supports only one foreign language at a time.For some languages they don't have code page table's so we need pay extra for that.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, we can use `ESC R 15` to set Chinese characters.

However, we have to do the Initialize command first.

[EPSON ESC R Command](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=29)

> the selected international character set is effective until ESC @ is executed, the printer is reset, or the power is turned off.